# SVN mark branched version in trunk

Tags: svn, branch

I used the "Branch / Tag"-function of TortoiseSVN to create a new branch. But I cant that I did the copy in the log of a file !in the trunk! In my old company this was possible, but I cant reproduce it.

A log of file xy in the trunk should look someway like this:

- **Revision/Date/Message**
- 19/19.5.2018/some change Message
- Branched to "branches/Version 1.0.0.1
- 17/16.5.2018/another change Message
- 15/14.5.2018/changed XY
- Branched to "branches/Version 1.0.0.0
- 11/12.5.2018/change XY
- 10/11.5.2018/first creation

How to see in the trunk, if a file was branched?

Answer (score 0):

If you did a branch/tag of the trunk, you won't see the revision of it *inside* the trunk, you would see that revision one directory above it (conventionally, unless it was branched elsewhere for whatever reason).

For example if your directory is as follows:

```
MyRepo
|_ MyProject
  |_trunk
  |_branches
  |_tags
  |_releases
```

It seems to me like you're looking for the revision in your trunk. You should be performing `svn log` under **MyProject**, as this will contain the revision in which it was branched. Likewise, you can also perform `svn log` under the branches/tags directory.

Comment: But I want to see the information in every log !inside! the trunk. And I am sure that there is a way because in my old company it was that way. Maybe there is another step necessary. a dummy revision? Or a svn-extention?

Comment: There’s nothing special about the trunk in which you need to see every revision in the repository. It would completely defeat the purpose of having sub-folder version history if it showed you commits from parent/sibling directories. Your old company may have had you working directly from the root of a project (not completely uncommon) and the branch was simply in another directory.

Comment: I dont want to see every revision. I just want to see a "marker" where I can see in the log which version of the file was branched to Version xy. This is useful because I can see which version of the file was used as the basis for version XY.